# TFS - Build Automation InvokeProcess issue

Tags: tfs, iis-express

I have automation build setup in TFS which is using InvokeProcess step. In this step, I am running a batch(*.bat) file which internally starts IISExpress.

My TFS build is running and it is starting IISExpress without any problem but this build is not going to the next step and it is waiting for the exit code or response from the batch file. How to override this functionalty as TFS build shouldn't wait for the result from the batch file and it should continue running the next steps.

I have configured the result of the InvokeProcess to take from an integer variable i.e.1 but still it is waiting for some result to be sent back.

My batch file consists the following code to start IISExpress

CD C:\Program Files\IIS Express
 iisexpress /config:C:\Users\a.b\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config /site:CloudWebRole

(CloudWebRole is a website)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Prav

Answer (score 1):

Option-1:
you can use following command in your batch file.

```
start iisexpress /config:C:\Users\a.b\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config /site:CloudWebRole
```

one thing to note is, it would popup a iisexpress.exe console window.

Option-2:
If don't want to see the popup console window, write a simple managed wrapper program (say iisexpresswrapper.exe) which just launches iisexpress.exe with the given arguments in the background and returns immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that you didn't need this anymore, but I faced the same problem today and find a solution :

1. Create a Parallel
2. Create a variable on Parallel (BuildFinished, in the picture) and fill the CompletionCondition of the Parallel
3. Assign True to BuildFinished in the build process' finally

Like this :

[image: TFSBUILD]